# Testing the availability of std::byte

Tags: c++, c++17, std-byte

I'd like to use C++17's `std::byte` type if it's available, and fall back to using `unsigned char` if not, i.e. something along the lines of

```
#include <cstddef>

namespace my {
#if SOMETHING
using byte = std::byte;
#else
using byte = unsigned char;
#endif
}
```

Unfortunately it seems that `std::byte` didn't come come with the usual feature test macro, so it's not obvious what `SOMETHING` above should be. (AFAIK the value of `__cplusplus` for '17 hasn't been set yet, so I can't test for that either.)

So, does anybody know of a way to detect whether `std::byte` is available on the big three compilers?

Comment: Boost might have you covered with [`boost::config`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/config/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: There is also `gsl::byte` https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/tree/master/include/gsl

Comment: I deleted my answer because it is technically incorrect, though I'm almost certain it will work. Basically you can forward declare `std::byte`, and then detect whether or not it is complete. The problem is that even forward declaring a class from namespace `std` is technically UB.

Comment: Why? If `unsigned char` does what you need, use it. Otherwise you'll have two different sets of code to maintain. Don't jump through hoops to use the latest feature just because it's there.

Comment: @Galik `gsl::byte` doesn't have the aliasing property `std::byte` has. That requires compiler support.

Comment: @NirFriedman `std::byte` is a scoped enumeration, not a class.

Comment: For C++17, `__cplusplus` is `201703L`.

Comment: @T.C. I stand corrected. But the same technique can be made to work with the enum class, no?

Comment: @NirFriedman No, it can't.

Comment: @T.C. I think I see. For anyone else: while it is possible to forward declare an enum class, I don't know if it's possible to detect whether an enum class is a complete or not. For a class one uses the fact that `sizeof` can only be called on complete classes, but for enums it seems like `sizeof` works on a forward declaration.

Comment: @T.C. Are you sure? It's underlying type is `unsigned char`, isn't that able to alias anything?

Comment: More to the point: an *opaque-enum-declaration* always declares a complete enumeration type with a fixed underlying type (`int` by default for scoped enums). An incomplete enumeration type is extremely rare and can only occur within its own definition.

Comment: @Galik `unsigned char` can alias anything. "Enumeration type whose underlying type is `unsigned char`" is not "`unsigned char`" and doesn't alias everything (unless the standard by special rule says it does, which is the case for `std::byte`).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to test availability of `std::byte` introduced by C++17, you should use `__cpp_lib_byte` macro (full list of feature testing macros is [here](https://wg21.link/sd6)).

The sample usage:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

#if __cpp_lib_byte
using byte = std::byte;
#else
using byte = unsigned char;
#endif

int main() {
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: This is obviously the right way to do it today, but the `__cpp_lib_byte` macro didn't exist at the time I asked the question (or I wouldn't have bothered asking it!). It seems it was added at some point in the '20 development cycle.

Comment: @TristanBrindle Yes. It must have been added recently.

Answer (score 3):

For C++17, the value of `__cplusplus` is [`201703L`](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.predefined#1.1). But that's not super useful.

Instead, you should look at [SD-6](https://wg21.link/sd6). This document contains all the feature test macros for all features adopted into C++, and the vendors all agree to follow them. It's possible that an implementation provides a feature but not the macro (e.g. gcc 7.2 supports `std::byte` but does not provide the macro) and more obviously that an implementation provides a feature and a macro but the feature is buggy, but you should rely on the macro. That's what it's there for.

Note that using `unsigned char` gives you almost the exact same behavior as `std::byte` - the only difference being that `unsigned char` supports extra arithmetic operations. So having an inexact check for `std::byte` support is okay - as long as you test on some compiler that supports `std::byte` to verify that you're not doing anything untoward, you're fine.

Comment: Note: the "SD Feature Test" (SD-6, https://isocpp.org/std/standing-documents/sd-6-sg10-feature-test-recommendations) link Barry cited above is still current as of Summer/2023.  It was last updated 2023-08-12.